# Bash script for monitor the API json response

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting, json

I want to monitor the below health check URL. I need generate a alert if mongodb goes to disconnected state. I wrote a bash script. Seems its still not working. Any can help on this ? Thanks

When do health check to https://www.example.com/healthz result as below response: `{"mongodb":"connected","redis":"connected"}`

And my Bash script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
data=$(wget --timeout 5 -O - -q -t 1 https://www.example.com/healthz)
message=$(jq '.Disconnected' <<< "$data")
if [[ "$message" == '"Success"' ]] ;  then
    echo something
else
    send email
```

Comment: You need a fi, Are the quotes on Success correct? You also need quotes on `$()`. I.E `"$(...)"`

Comment: Crossposting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60902155/3776858

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `.Disconnected` key in the JSON response.

To check the `.mongodb` key for the string `connected` you may do this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if wget --timeout 5 -O - -q -t 1 https://www.example.com/healthz |
   jq --exit-status '.mongodb == "connected"' >/dev/null
then
    # code for the case when MongoDB is connected
else
    # code for the case when MongoDB is *not* connected
fi
```

This passes the response directly from `wget` to `jq` instead of going the roundabout way of storing it in an intermediate variable.

Using `--exit-status` (or `-e`) with `jq` makes the utility exit with a successful exit status (zero) if it does not output `nil` or `false`.  The expression we give to `jq` will output `true` if the `.mongodb` key has the value `connected`.

We then use the exit status of `jq` in the `if` statement to choose the branch to take.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kusalananda .its worked